# OAuth2RestTemplate with multiple contexts

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm writing a standalone (not web based) application that will act as a client on behalf of multiple resource owners. Since the authorization server binds access tokens to specific resource owners, I will have to manage multiple access tokens.

I would like to use the Spring `RestTemplate` to access the protected resource on the resource server. The problem is that the `OAuth2RestTemplate` implementation is bound to a specific `OAuth2ClientContext` while I need to maintain one context per resource owner.

I thought about overriding the `RestTemplate` class using `OAuth2RestTemplate` as base. The idea is to keep an internal mapping of resource owner IDs to `OAuth2ClientContext`s. The problem is how to pass the resource owner ID when calling one of the methods defined in the `RestOperations` interface. Before interacting with the resource server, I need to know which resource owner is concerned so that I can find an existing `OAuth2ClientContext` (or create a new one if it doesn't exist).

Before I move on, I wanted to ask if someone solved the same problem using a more elegant solution and if not, do you have recommendations about how to solve this kind of issue?

Thanks,
Mickael

Comment: Normally you just have multiple `OAuth2RestTemplate` instances, and use the one that's appropriate for the resource you want to access. What is it that's special about your problem?

Comment: @DaveSyer You're right, this was my first direction. However, I thought that creating one OAuth2RestTemplate per resource owner would not be performant at all. Especially, since I'm interacting with the same server, I wanted to reuse TCP connections but I don't think it's possible when multiple OAuth2RestTemplate are used, right?

Comment: TCP? You mean raw TCP not "HTTP over TCP"? No that's not supported out of the box (OAuth2 is designed to be an HTTP protocol, although I have heard of people using it over other transports). I don't see what the performance problem would be, which isn't to say that there might not be a problem, but I never guess about performance, always measure it.

Comment: No I meant HTTP over TCP. In order to send HTTP requests, TCP connections are created by the template. However, if multiple templates are used, TCP connections are reused over the same template, not across the multiple templates. The point is that I'm interacting with a single resource server but on behalf of multiple resource owners. Therefore, TCP connections should be reused to improve performance. However, I can't reuse TCP connections when using multiple templates.

Comment: Illustrating by an example: if I have two resource owners A and B and I first interact with the resource server on behalf of A, a new TCP connection is created by the template associated to A. Then, if I interact with the same resource server on behalf of B, a new TCP connection is created by the template associated to B. Imagine this interaction will be done on behalf of thousands of clients... Therefore, I thought that creating a new template with multi client contexts support would be a good idea.

Comment: I see. Is that maybe a concern that you can handle at the HTTP client level, and share one between all your rest templates (via a client http request factory)?

Comment: @DaveSyer Thanks, I created a ClientHttpRequestFactory based on HTTP Components, and shared by all the RestTemplate. The problem I have now is that TCP connection is closed after each use. I found the problematic line of code. It is in RestTemplate in method doExecute. You can see in the finally block the call to response.close(). After the entity is consumed, the stream is closed and therefore the TCP connection is closed. I use the default HttpClient configuration.

Comment: I guess that's a problem for `RestTemplate` in your use case generally then?

Comment: I think it's a general problem for all RestTemplate users, no? The RestTemplate should not close the connection but should rely on the underlying implementation (in my case the Apache HttpClient) for what to do. For example, the underlying connection manager may keep the TCP connection open for future use.

Comment: You control the client, so you can probably control the implementation of the close() method. I'm not sure I can help you any more with that though.

Comment: The Spring code calls the close() method of HttpComponentsClientHttpResponse which closes the TCP connection. However, connection persistence is enabled. Are you sure this call to close() is correct?

Comment: I think I can see the problem: the Spring code closes the content stream instead of closing the response. According to the Apache doc, closing the content stream implies closing the connection. Please see section 1.1.5 in http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html.

Comment: @DaveSyer Should I conclude that RestTemplate doesn't allow using connection persistence feature of Apache HttpClient?

Comment: I'm not the right person to ask. Try a new post? Or an issue in JIRA?

Comment: I've opened an issue in JIRA. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12524